How to smoothly move and return objects relative to a moving reference in Unity
im not sure if this is even the right place to ask about stuff like this, but my friend said i can ask anything coding related here.
So to start, This here is my player character
Im trying to add a mechanic where the fists next to the player shoot out a bit infront and then return to the player.
My main problem is writing the code for the fists returning to the player who constantly moves.
Shooting out the fist itself should not be a problem, since i can just copy my dash mechanic from my player ( I think? correct me if im wrong, ill post the player and fist scripts later on)
Thanks already for answers!
This is my player Script:
public class ManScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D myMan;
    public float moveSpeed = 7;
 
    public float activeMoveSpeed;
    public float dashSpeed;
 
    public float dashLength = .5f, dashCD = 1f;
 
    private float dashCounter;
    private float dashCooldown;
 
    public float HP, MaxHP;
 
 
    [SerializeField]
    private HealthScript healthBar;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        activeMoveSpeed = moveSpeed;
        healthBar.SetMaxHealth(MaxHP);
        HP = MaxHP;
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
     
     
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            myMan.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.right * activeMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
 
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            myMan.MovePosition(transform.position - transform.right * activeMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
 
        }
 
 
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            myMan.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.up * activeMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
         
 
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            myMan.MovePosition(transform.position - transform.up * activeMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
         
 
        }
 
 
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            myMan.MovePosition(transform.position + (transform.up - transform.right).normalized * activeMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
 
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            myMan.MovePosition(transform.position - (transform.up - transform.right).normalized * activeMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
 
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            myMan.MovePosition(transform.position - (transform.up + transform.right).normalized * activeMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
 
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            myMan.MovePosition(transform.position + (transform.up + transform.right).normalized * activeMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (dashCooldown <= 0 && dashCounter <= 0)
            {
                activeMoveSpeed = dashSpeed;
                dashCounter = dashLength;
            }
        }
        if (dashCounter > 0)
        {
            dashCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
 
            if (dashCounter <= 0)
            {
                activeMoveSpeed = moveSpeed;
                dashCooldown = dashCD;
 
            }
        }
        if (dashCooldown > 0)
        {
            dashCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J))
        {
            SetHealth(-20f);
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.K))
        {
            SetHealth(20f);
        }
 
        if(HP <= 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        }
 
     
 
 
 
    }
   public void SetHealth(float healthChange)
    {
        HP += healthChange;
        HP = Mathf.Clamp(HP, 0, MaxHP);
 
        healthBar.SetHealth(HP);
    }
     
}

And this is the script for the fists, which is just to rotate them to the position im moving in
public class FakeLeft : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {




    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.forward * 180;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.forward * 360;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.forward * 90;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.forward * 270;
        }

    }
}


Please chose a more descriptive title for your question ... for instance something along "How to smoothly move and return objects relative to a moving reference" or "How to smoothly move rigidbodies relative to a moving reference as if they were in local space?"

Parent them to the Player GameObject if not already and then move them in local space using transform.localPosition

thanks! i will try that as soon as i can? So i use the transform.localPosition when i want to return them, right? Not when shooting them out.
